# Passing multiple OS CRAN checks

Tags: r, cran

I am suddenly having issues with one of my packages not passing the CRAN web check across operating system builds. The issues seem to be limited to certain linux and Mac OS-X flavors but, not all. I have a NOTE on 4 and an ERROR on one. My package submission was just bounced back because of this.

Here is the link to the CRAN check results for the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_spatialEco.html

This seems to be related to rgdal, which is actually a dependency coming from one of my dependencies, albeit an important one, and not a direct call from my package.

If this were an issue across all linux platforms I would certainly be figuring out how to address this on the code side but, it seems to be related to the ongoing problem with the R port to GDAL on OS-X and certain linux flavors. Any ideas on how to get to where I am CRAN compliant? Is this considered a false rejection. I should note that this is new and the last I looked at package checks for this package version, they were clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is explained in your CRAN check notes [here](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-oldrel-osx-x86_64/spatialEco-00install.html):

> ERROR: this R is version 3.3.2, package 'spatialEco' requires R >=  3.4.0

The error is on an "old-rel" (i.e., old release) version of R, typically the `Current-1.Minor.Patch`.

I'm assuming you bumped the R dependency for some reason? Generally, if you don't actually need a dependency on a specific version of R, it's best to leave this out or to set it to the lowest possible release number. If you need that dependency, then this is probably safe to ignore.

The NOTEs you're seeing are due to the fact that you have **rgdal** in your DESCRIPTION `Imports` field but you do not actually import any functions from the package in your NAMESPACE file (via `@import` tags).

Comment: Thank you for a nice clear answer. I bumped the R dependency because another package did, but not sure why. I had a call to rgdal that I aimed towards another package in this release and completely forgot to remove it from the required packages.